# Include NA in linear model in R

Tags: r, na, lm

I have a question about how to include the NA value in the vector after doing a regression.

Here is my code:

```
m <- c(100, 108, 105, 120)
n <- c(5, NA, 10, 8)

b <- lm(n~m)$fitted.values

# This returns:

       1        3        4 
6.961538 7.384615 8.653846
```

I need column 2 to be included as well, either with Zero or NA, so that it consists of 4 columns instead of 3. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: Need to call the prediction again. `predict(lm(n~m),data.frame(m=c(100, 108, 105, 120)))`

Answer (score 2):

In order your extracted fitted values will include also NA (i.e. 4 columns) you can use `na.exclude` inside `lm()`

`na.exclude` does casewise deletion with respect to predictors and criterions and in this case function `fitted()` will fill output with `NA`

So your code looks like this

```
m <- c(100, 108, 105, 120)
n <- c(5, NA, 10, 8)

# ordinary linear model
b <- lm(n~m, na.action = na.exclude)

# extract elements from a linear model fit
fitted(b)

# And output of NA column
fitted(b)
       1        2        3        4 
6.961538       NA 7.384615 8.653846
```